# Gridview show few lines of data in one record

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, grid

I was using Gridview for a while now and I have noticed that its very easy to create a simple table and populate it with date f.e.

```
ID Name Surename Phone .....

1 Tom   Tomtom    111122233 
2 Vic   VicVic    21231231
3 Rik   RikRik    123545343
```

So here we have a simple gridview with three records, every record is in one line!
What I need is to put one record info in three lines like here:

```
           ID Name Surename Phone .....

         / 1 Tom   Tomtom    111122233 
record1 {  Additional info: blablabla
         \ More info: xxxxx 
         / 2 Vic   VicVic    21231231
record2 {  Additional info: blablabla
         \ More info: xxxxx 
         / 3 Rik   RikRik    123545343
record3 {  Additional info: blablabla
         \ More info: xxxxx
```

So here we have a Gridview and here we show One record's info in three lines...So how to do this?

I was using this code to populate my gridview when I have an Object of data but this works only with a single lines of records

```
private void grdMyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                MyObject ObjectEl = (MyObject)e.Row.DataItem;
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = ObjectEl.ID.ToString();
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = ObjectEl.Name.ToString();
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = ObjectEl.Surename.ToString();

                LinkButton lbtConfigure = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[3].FindControl("lbtConfigure");
                lbtConfigure.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(ObjectEl.ID);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templating rows like this is possible in a gridview, but the listview control is much better suited to this type of data.

Take a look here, this will get you started.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx

Comment: I honestly believe this CAN't solve my problem, but you have tried :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use templating for this purpose.
insert tables inside header template and item template(according to your need).
inside tables you can insert labels.
bind labels with the columns in your datatable.(Eval("columnname")).
now you got the gridview as you expected.